# How nodejs cluster master and worker process communicate to each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, cluster-computing, ipc

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works

In this link they mentioned  node worker process is communicate with the parent via IPC.

There are many ways in IPC two process are communicate with each other?

- Pipes
- List item
- Signals
- Message
- Queues
- Semaphores
- Shared
- Memory
- Sockets
- Namedpipes

In what way Nodejs master and worker process communicated?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Simple, My boss is asked this question:) and then I want to learn internal working of nodejs cluster deeply.

Comment: Then your boss is definetly asking the wrong questions...